# How to get information about users whose email is known in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have the following data in Firebase:

(I am not allowed to attach images yet in Stackoverflow):

There is a root node -> root has a child node called "NewStaffRequests". "NewStaffRequests" has multiple users with unique id's. Under each unique id, one particular users' email-id and role keys are present. The 'role' key could have values such as "Trainer".

The email-id is already regsitered in the auth system. In the future, there will be many more such users with unique id, email-id and role. I want to login, retrieve the role of a user whose email-id is obtained from email-id TextView in the Activity, find this email-id in "NewStaffRequests" and obtain the role of that user. I have written the following code for this. But, the object 'StaffUser value' only gets null. Please advise!

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_staff_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        heading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heading);
        note = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.note);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterEmail);
        pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterPassword);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.roles_spinner);

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);


        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                final String staffEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
                final String password = pwd.getText().toString().trim();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(staffEmail))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You must enter your E-Mail!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You must enter your Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

          }

                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(staffEmail,password).addOnCompleteListener(StaffLogin.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "successfull login : " + task.isSuccessful());

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(StaffLogin.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else {

                            DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                            Query reference = root.child("NewStaffRequests").orderByChild("email").equalTo(staffEmail);
                            reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {

                                        StaffUser value = dataSnapshot.getValue(StaffUser.class);
                                        String staffRole = value.role;

                                        if(staffRole.equals("Fitness Trainer"))
                                        {
                                            startActivity(new Intent(StaffLogin.this, RMLanding.class));
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The user is someone else", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }


                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And, following is the StaffUser class :

```
public class StaffUser {

    public String email, name, role;
    public Boolean approvalStatus;

    public StaffUser() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public StaffUser(String _email, String _name,String _role,Boolean _approvalStatus) {

        this.email = _email;
        this.name = _name;
        this.role = _role;
        this.approvalStatus = _approvalStatus;
    }
}
```

Following is the error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference.
```

And the line where this error points to is:

```
String staffRole = value.role;
```

Changes made after Alex's suggestion :

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(staffEmail,password).addOnCompleteListener(StaffLogin.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "successfull login : " + task.isSuccessful());

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(StaffLogin.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else {

                            DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                            Query reference = root.child("NewStaffRequests").orderByChild("email").equalTo(staffEmail);
                            reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0) {


                                        //Toast.makeText(StaffLogin.this, "datasnapshot value" + dataSnapshot.getValue(StaffUser.class), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        StaffUser value = dataSnapshot.getValue(StaffUser.class);//When I attach the debugger on this line, I can see that 'value' is null, but dataSnapshot.getValue(StaffUser.class) is showing the stored database values from firebase.
                                        Log.d(TAG, "datasnapshot value" + value.getRole());

                                        String staffRole = value.getRole();

                                        if(staffRole.equals("Rescue Manager"))
                                        {
                                            startActivity(new Intent(StaffLogin.this, RMLanding.class));
                                            finish();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The user is someone else", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        }


                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });


                        }



                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get this error, `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference`, it means that `staffRole` String is `null`.

To solve this, you need to use the following line of code:

```
String staffRole = value.getRole();
```

This also means that you need to add this method inside your model class like this:

```
public String getRole() {
    return role;
}
```

Note, that you need to add public getters to all of your fields and the fields itself must be private and not public as I see in your class. Your class should look like this:

```
public class StaffUser {
    private String email, name, role;
    private boolean approvalStatus;

    public StaffUser() {}

    public StaffUser(String email, String name, String role, Boolean approvalStatus) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
        this.approvalStatus = approvalStatus;
    }

    public String getEmail() {return email;}

    public String getName() {return name;}

    public String getRole() {return role;}

    public boolean getApprovalStatus() {return approvalStatus;}
}
```

To get the actual objects, please use the follwing code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("NewStaffRequests").orderByChild("email").equalTo(staffEmail);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            StaffUser value = dataSnapshot.getValue(StaffUser.class);
            Log.d("TAG", value.getRole());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Thank you, Alex! I have changed the StaffUser class as you have mentioned (I added getter and setter methods). But still I see the same error. Here is where the issue is when I try to debug :

StaffUser value = dataSnapshot.getValue(StaffUser.class);

When I attach the debugger, i can see that dataSnapshot.getValue(StaffUser.class); is indeed getting the values from the database. But at the same time, value, which is of the type StaffUser is null. I don't understand why 'value' is not being assigned any values.

Comment: Here, means where? Have you changed this line of code `String staffRole = value.role;` with `String staffRole = value.getRole();`?

Comment: Sorry, Please see the main question. I have added a new section with the edited code. Please see the long comment I have mentioned.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, Alex ! Works like a charm :)